# Get unique values in column separated by comma

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a classic ASP online form to submit and insert data into this table. This form will insert multiple rows into a table. The form will gather some checkboxes and insert True for checked and False for unchecked on Status column.

I tried to create a query to `STUFF Menu_id` that has True Status, separate by a comma.

For example:

- In the first `Refnumber 12121313`, its outputs should be: `12121313   1, 4`
- In the second `Refnumber 28273882`, its outputs should be: `28273882   1, 2, 3`

I tried a query below, but it shows error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ', ' to data type int

```
ID   Refnumber   Menu_id   Status
------------------------------------
01   12121313    1          True
02   12121313    2          False
03   12121313    3          False
04   12121313    4          True

05   28273882    1          True
06   28273882    2          True
07   28273882    3          True
08   28273882    4          False
```

This is my query :

```
SELECT  ID, Refnumber, Status
Menu_id = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Menu_id
           FROM Report b 
           WHERE b.Refnumber = a.Refnumber 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM Report a
GROUP BY  ID, Refnumber,Menu_id,Status
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by this simple way, live demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=32afcadfb70b5251911af2c21c83dc3f)

```
SELECT DISTINCT C2.Refnumber, 
SUBSTRING(
(
   SELECT ', ' + CAST(C1.Menu_id AS VARCHAR(20))
   FROM TempTable C1
   WHERE C1.Refnumber = C2.Refnumber AND C1.Status = 'True'
  FOR XML PATH ('')
), 2, 1000) AS "MenuIdList"
FROM TempTable C2
```

**Output**

```
Refnumber   MenuIdList
12121313     1, 4
28273882     1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Jenny Tran

Answer (score 1):

Use `CONCAT()` :

```
SELECT ID, Refnumber, Status
       Menu_id = STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(', ',b.Menu_id)
                        FROM Report b 
                        WHERE b.Refnumber = a.Refnumber 
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                       ), 1, 2, ''
                      ) 
FROM Report a
GROUP BY ID, Refnumber, Status;
```

`CONCAT()` is available `SQL Server 12 or +`, you can also do conversation :

```
SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), b.Menu_id)
```

Comment: 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name. Thanks.